# No puedo mapear una clase en el Web.xml en Java

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, httpservletresponse

No consigo mapear una clase en la cual recojo peticiones POST de un JSP y necesitaria ayuda para solucionarlo. El resultado que espero es poder crear unos input en el JSP dependiendo de la consulta que tengo en otra parte pero el problema es no poder acceder a la clase por no estar mapeada. La clase java es la siguiente:

```
package es.cepsa.contratos.web.datoscontratos.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import es.cepsa.contratos.auxiliares.datoscontratos.ValoresCampo;

public class ValoresCampoAjax extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            CEGCAL1Bean AL1Bean;
            AL1Bean = new CEGCAL1Bean();
            final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            final String servicio = request.getParameter("servicio");
            ArrayList<ValoresCampo> valoresCampo = new ArrayList<ValoresCampo>();
            String nombreCampo;
            String valor;
            String aplicaContrato;

            if (servicio != null && !servicio.equals("")) {
                valoresCampo = AL1Bean.getCamposServicio(servicio);
            }

            for(int i = 0; i <= valoresCampo.size();i++){
                 nombreCampo = valoresCampo.get(i).getNombre();
                 valor = valoresCampo.get(i).getValor();
                 aplicaContrato = valoresCampo.get(i).getAplicaContrato();

                if(aplicaContrato.equals("SI")){
                    out.println("<tr>"
                            + "<td class=\"texto\" align=\"right\"><nobr>" + nombreCampo+ "</nobr></td>"
                            + "<td><IMG height=1 src=\"../../../general/imagenes/pix.gif\" width=10 border=0></td>"
                            + "<td><input type=text name=\""+ nombreCampo +"\" class=\"texto\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"8\" value=\"" + valor + "\"></td>"
                            + "</tr>");
                }else{


                    out.println("<tr>"
                            + "<td class=\"texto\" align=\"right\"><nobr>" + nombreCampo + "</nobr></td>"
                            + "<td><IMG height=1 src=\"../../../general/imagenes/pix.gif\" width=10 border=0></td>"
                            + "<td><input type=text name=\""+ nombreCampo +"\" class=\"texto\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"8\" value=\"" + valor + " readonly \"></td>"
                            + "</tr>");
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

En el JSP tengo un metodo onChange que me accede  bien a el pero no lanza la peticion a la pagina:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectServicioExtra").change(function(){
            console.log("entra");
            var idServicio = $('#selectServicioExtra').val();
            // Si en vez de por post lo queremos hacer por get, cambiamos el $.post por $.get
            $.post('ValoresCampoAjax', {
                servicio : idServicio   
            }, function(responseText) {
                console.log("entra respuesta");
                $('#camposServicioResultados').html(responseText);
            });
        });
    });
```

y la parte del web.xml que he añadido seria la siguiente:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ValoresCampoAjax</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>es.cepsa.contratos.web.datoscontratos.beans.ValoresCampoAjax</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ValoresCampoAjax</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bean/ValoresCampoAjax</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

No consigo que funcione de ninguna manera. Agradeceria muchisimo la ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servlet está correctamente configurado en el web.xml, el problema es que no coinciden las peticiones que atiende el servlet con la llamada que haces desde javascript.
La etiqueta `<url-pattern>/bean/ValoresCampoAjax</url-pattern>` indica que el servlet atiende peticiones en la ruta `http://localhost:8080/bean/ValoresCampoAjax` y desde javascript estas llamando a `http://localhost:8080/ValoresCampoAjax`

Modifica el javascript:

```
...
$.post('bean/ValoresCampoAjax', {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sé poco de servlets, pero creo que DEBEN sobreescribir los métodos doGet, doPost (que son los que tienes) y además, el processRequest.

Prueba añadirla dejando el cuerpo vacío como en el doGet. Pero no estoy muy seguro, puesto que este error te lo debería decir el IDE. Es decir, extender una clase obliga a sobreescribir sus métodos abstractos aunque eso lo sabe perfectamente el entorno, y por eso no creo que te esté ayudando mucho. No se me ocurre nada más.

Comment: Antetodo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta @carles. El problema que estoy teniendo es con el fichero web.xml que no estoy seguro como configurarlo y no se como hacer para que me mapee bien la clase. Los metodos get y post si no me equivoco estan sobreescritos al poner el tag "@override".